# group_concat inserting double quote for empty values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I have some data stored in table as comma separated string  in user_values column, so as per my requirement I want to get specific user data and  values stored in user_values column should get in single quote for this purpose I am using below query and it is working fine, but if specific user doesn't have any value in user_values column then  below query getting user_values with one double quote inserted however it should get empty value for that column , so how to prevent double quote if column is empty for specific user.

table

```
id    user_values
1     1,2
2     3,4,5
3              // empty / no value for this user
4     4,7
```

mysql query:

case 1:  if user 1 have values in user_values column then

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("'", REPLACE(user_values,",", "','") , "'")) as user_val 
FROM user 
WHERE id=1;
```

output:

[image]

case 2:  if user don't have any value then inserting double in empty column

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("'", REPLACE(user_values,",", "','") , "'")) as user_val 
FROM user 
WHERE id=3;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Why `REPLACE(user_values,",", "','")`? Do you have commas *within* column `user_values`?

Comment: yes I have comma

Comment: Why not normalise your schema? Failing that, why bother with an RBDMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the some values of `user_values` are empty strings (which are different than `null` values, that `group_concat()` ignores). You can work around this with a `case` expression within `group_concat()` that turns empty strings to `null` values, like:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE
        WHEN user_values = '' THEN NULL 
        ELSE CONCAT("'", REPLACE(user_values,",", "','"), "'")
    END) as user_val 
FROM user 
WHERE id = 3;
```

Comment: thanks a lot it is working can you please explain little bit about this case

Comment: @user_1234: see my updated answer. The problem is with empty strings.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with GMB's diagnosis of the issue.  However, I think that `NULLIF()` provides a simpler solution:

```
SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT( NULLIF(CONCAT("'", REPLACE(user_values, ",", "','") , "'"), "''"
                    ) as user_val 
FROM user 
WHERE id = 3 ;
```